# Mock a method from implicit class in specs2

Tags: scala, mocking, mockito, specs2

Say I have a class and a related implicit class:

```
class Project
implicit class RichProject(p:Project) {
  def searchFile(keyword:String):Seq[File] = {
    p.getFiles.filter(_.name.contains(keyword))
  }
}
```

Then I want to mock the `searchFile` method for a `project` in a specs2 test:

```
val project = mock[Project]
project.searchFile("aa") returns Seq(new File("/aaa"))
```

But it reports a `NullPointException` that seems it's running inside the real `searchFile` instead of mocking it.

Is it possible to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write `project.searchFile` then `searchFile` is not a method which belongs to the mocked object but to the `RichProject` class. So Mockito can not mock it and will try to execute it.

I don't fix there is a fix for this other than mocking the `RichProject` class itself.

Comment: Thanks Eric. The `RichProject` will be created implicitly, it doesn't appear in the method being tested (since we can just use `project.searchFile` directly), how can I pass in the mocked `RichProject`?

Comment: You can maybe override an `implicit def RichProject(p:Project)` method so that it always return a mock of `RichProject`.

Comment: So we have to use `implicit def ` rather than `implicit class` in order to make it mockable, right?